# IRF540N based battery discharger

Tags: mosfet

I am building an ESP-based aeronautical battery capacity tester: a timed, current regulated, discharger. I got a partial schematic on the internet and, thanks to this forum, I learned [at least] one component was totally wrong. Now I am facing a second problem with the IRF540N. I am just testing separate components to verify they work as planned.

The current flow is [now] adjusted to 3.3A via an op-amp connected to the gate, in the final project, this controlling voltage is supplied through a DAC. This is my test configuration:
[image: Configuration for test]

Test steps:
-5v independent power supply to the LM324N
-Adjustable power supply 0-30V 5A max to the battery connector, set to 5V.
-Adjust the POT to have a current of 3.3A
-Increase the voltage and verify the current remains 3.3A - OK!
-Works fine up to almost 12-13v, mosfet still cold.
-At almost 15V, the current jumps to 5A, limited by the PS
-the mosfet is cold but fried, shorted!

On the datasheet for IRF540N I read 33(23)A, 100V, 140W. I thought it is good enough to work at 28V 3.3A but it fried at ~15V in lesst than one second. Am I missing something? I have a huge heatsink with fan, I think I reached 66W or less and it fried! No time anyway to heat up.

Comment: _"I thought it is good enough"_ _"I think I reached"_ Don't! Measure! Why don't you have a resistor in series? What does the datasheet say about allowable SOAR?

Comment: @winny: I don't have a resistor in series while, as I anticipated in my first post, I am totally new in analog electronics and, for me, 23A, 100V , 140W were more than enough for my needs.

Comment: @Andy aka thanks! I didn't understand the importance of that diagram even if I have noticed it on the datasheet! I will place a multi watt resistor on the + side. Still I am not sure how to read the diagram. With 3.3A (or, better, 5A to have a safety margin) what is the max voltage drop I may have for infinite time?

Comment: @Resca the IRF540 isn't that good for your circuit; it's intended for switching applications and you have a "linear" application and therefore, it will always be operating the device in an area of its characteristics where it will suffer from thermal runaway (see fig 3 in data sheet). What that graph tells you is that with a gate drive voltage of 5 volts or less, the drain current can run out of control and rapidly (and I mean really rapidly) fail the device. The "infinite" time information is also not really available for this device either (fig 11 only goes to 10 seconds).

Comment: You should pick a MOSFET that is more suited to linear application such as several sold by [IXYS](https://www.littelfuse.com/search-results.aspx#t=PartsTab&f:@ftechnology30330=[power%20semiconductors]&f:@fproductsupercategory30330=[Discrete%20MOSFETs]&f:@fproductcategory30330=[n%20channel%20linear]).

Comment: Did C1 need to be 10 uF - in my previous answer I recommended 10 nF. It's not a bog deal - I just wondered why you chose 10 uF.

Comment: Than my best tip would be to simplify your problem by moving a significant portion of your losses to a resistor instead. Your maximum to minimum voltage span and same for current will set the limit for how much is possible. MOSFETs are nor meant for power dissipation but rather have to survive it as a secondary effect. Resistors on the other hand is your prime candidate for power dissipation.

Comment: @Andyaka, as for the cap, it is wrong on the drawing but i used the correct 10nF. I am sorry for my stupid questions, but I got the schematics from an "expert"... now I know he isn't! May you suggest me *one* of the trillion mosfets available at the site you indicated suitable for my needs? Or, better, what in particular have I to look for when I  have a "linear" application in contrast with a "switching" application? Thanks!

Comment: I think it's better if you pick one that is suitable for you package wise and I'll give it the once over. All the MOSFETs I linked above are suited for linear applications and, if it has words to that effect on the front page of the MOSFET data sheet it can be relied upon (should you generally want to look for other suppliers). It should also be noted that you can reasonably parallel these MOSFETs for half-decent load sharing without much risk of one device completely hogging all the current.

Comment: Ditto what @winny says too - if you can get more power dissipation into a series resistor and use the MOSFET for keeping the current constant it'll be far more reliable.

Comment: @andyaka yes, for sure I will add a 300W or more resistor on the plus side. The complete project has "3  times" the present schematic while I have to draw 10A! I never considered to parallel the mosfets "directly" while I read that it is not a good practice. In any case, I must handle from 28.8V to 20V and keep the current up to 10A,  so a 2 ohm resistor is too high, I think I need 1.5 ohm, a drop in the resistor of 15 volts and still 13.8 at the mosfets!

Comment: It's going to be a balancing act for sure.

Comment: @Andyaka, it is not easy to find those linear mosfets in Italy and most suppliers require to buy lots of 50. But I have some 2SD2560.The datasheet says 150V, 5A, 130W. I tried it **without** the load resistor and it survived 20 minutes al 29V, 3.3A. I turned the test off when the heatsink reached 100 degrees and the NPN is still happily alive for a new test. In the final project I have a larger heatsink and a fan but, mainly, with the series resistor, I will have at least half the voltage to handle. So I wonder why I cannot use a "regular" transistor instead of a mosfet!

Comment: @Resca you can use a regular transistor but you will get errors - to drive the device requires base current and that will flow through the sense resistor creating a false impression of collector current. However, the 2SD2560 is a darlington transistor so it's probably acceptable regarding errors because base current will be tiny. I don't know what the thermal resistance of the device is but I'd be concerned about the internal junction temperature exceeding 150 degC. However, you are on your way to a better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Am I missing something?*

I've taken the safe operating area graph from the data sheet and superimposed a couple of extra red lines that correspond to MOSFET active time durations of 100 ms and 1 second: -

[image]

The lines I've added will be roughly correct given that for a ten-fold increase in time period, the successive lines drop by about the same amount. But, it is open to interpretation I grant you.

However, if we assume that my extra lines are about right, then with a drain-source voltage of about 14 volts, we should not allow the drain current to be greater than about 3 amps for longer than 1 second.